# Use Postfix to dump mails to local folder using regex

Tags: email, postfix, regex

How do I use postfix to filter certain emails (by domain or sender) and for those who fall under the rule (filter) save locally and those who doesn't to relay regularly ?

Comment: To vote-to-closers: Why would this be offtopic? Postfix is in the `main` Ubuntu repositories and is the default MTA.

Comment: Should I ask this on Server Fault ?

Comment: You could ask on Server Fault. Question is on topic there and may get an answer quicker than here. But as pointed out by @gertvdijk its on topic here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following recipe tells how to use regex to rewrite envelope recipients' addresses using regexp: https://superuser.com/questions/353488/regex-multiple-catch-all-setup-in-postfix
You may use the above method to rewrite remote email addresses into local email addresses.

[Regexp table man page](http://postfix.ixp.jp/regexp_table.5.html) shows how to copy parts of lookup key to lookup result:

```
/^(.*)-outgoing@(.*)$/   550 Use ${1}@${2} instead
```

Comment: Indeed, thou this is not what I asked, how do I tell postfix to save the mail file locally if it falls under the regex ?

Comment: You may rewrite remote email addresses into local email addresses.